# GridView - Line break inside Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been trying to get a line break between this inside every cell in column 1:

Value 1, Value 2, 
Value 3

However the line breaks are just showing up as plain text in the cell:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dg1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="Sort" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dg1_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="DGgeneral" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DGheader" RowStyle-CssClass="DGrow1" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="DGrow2" >
    <Columns>

     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am doing everything programatically so I can't add `HTMLEncode="false"` to BoundFields which is a huge pain.

```
 public void SearchQuery(string sOrderBy, string sOrderByColumn)
    {
        //Create and Clear Datatable and Gridview

        dt.Clear();
        dg1.DataSource = null;
        dg1.DataBind();

        //Initialise Strings
        string sTLTaskID = "";
        string sTitle = "";
        string sForename = "";
        string sSurname = "";
        string sEmail = "";
        string sMobile = "";
        string sHome = "";
        string sDateTime = "";
        string sState = "";
        string sFormName = "";

        //Initialise Column Names

        dt.Columns.Add("Id/Form/State");
        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
        dt.Columns.Add("Forename");
        dt.Columns.Add("Surname");
        dt.Columns.Add("Email address");
        dt.Columns.Add("Telephone 1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Telephone 2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Date & Time");

        //Connect to ********
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
                                                    "Data Source = ******;" +
                                                    "Integrated Security = ******;" +
                                                    "persist security info = ******;" +
                                                    "Initial Catalog = ********;"))
        {
            //Establish SQL Command
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "********";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TLTaskID", txtTLTaskID.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MNumber", txtNumber.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HNumber", txtNumber.Text);

                if ((sOrderBy == null) || (sOrderBy == ""))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AscDesc", "");
                }
                else if (sOrderBy == "Asc")
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AscDesc", "Asc");
                }
                else if (sOrderBy == "Desc")
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AscDesc", "Desc");
                }

                if ((sOrderByColumn == null) || (sOrderByColumn == ""))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderByColumn", "");
                }
                else
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderByColumn", sOrderByColumn);
                }

                connection.Open();
                //Initialise Column Names
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var column1 = reader.GetOrdinal("TLTaskID");
                    var column2 = reader.GetOrdinal("Title");
                    var column3 = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName");
                    var column4 = reader.GetOrdinal("Surname");
                    var column5 = reader.GetOrdinal("Email");
                    var column6 = reader.GetOrdinal("Telephone1");
                    var column7 = reader.GetOrdinal("Telephone2");
                    var column8 = reader.GetOrdinal("DateTime");
                    var column9 = reader.GetOrdinal("State");
                    var column10 = reader.GetOrdinal("FormName");

                    //Loop until out of Rows in table
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Set values of each row to a variable
                        var TLTaskID = reader.GetValue(column1);
                        var Title = reader.GetValue(column2);
                        var Forename = reader.GetValue(column3);
                        var Surname = reader.GetValue(column4);
                        var Email = reader.GetValue(column5);
                        var Mobile = reader.GetValue(column6);
                        var Home = reader.GetValue(column7);
                        var DateTime = reader.GetValue(column8);
                        var State = reader.GetValue(column9);
                        var FormName = reader.GetValue(column10);

                        //Convert to strings //Possible speed up ****
                        sTLTaskID = TLTaskID.ToString();
                        sTitle = Title.ToString();
                        sForename = Forename.ToString();
                        sSurname = Surname.ToString();
                        sEmail = Email.ToString();
                        sMobile = Mobile.ToString();
                        sHome = Home.ToString();
                        sDateTime = DateTime.ToString();
                        sState = State.ToString();
                        sFormName = FormName.ToString();

                        //Add to DataTable
                        var dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Id/Form/State"] = sTLTaskID + ", " + sFormName + ", " + sState;
                        dr["Title"] = sTitle;
                        dr["Forename"] = sForename;
                        dr["Surname"] = sSurname;
                        dr["Email address"] = sEmail;
                        dr["Telephone 1"] = sMobile;
                        dr["Telephone 2"] = sHome;
                        dr["Date & Time"] = sDateTime;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                        //Set GridView's datasource to Datatable dr
                        dg1.DataSource = dt;
                        dg1.DataBind();                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int iRowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        if (iRowCount > 0)
        {
            lblRecordTotal.Text = "Records: 1 - " + iRowCount.ToString() + " of " + iRowCount.ToString(); 
        }
        else
        {
            lblRecordTotal.Text = "No records found.";
        }
    }
```

If anything more is required please ask away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a <br/> tag?

Comment: I have done so. It's just displaying as Plain text rather than actually making a line break

Comment: where you want to add `HTMLEncode="false"`?

Comment: I can't add it into the Bound Fields as i am automatically generating the columns.

Comment: add this using `RowDataBound` event of gridview as programatically.

Comment: Could you give me code snippet to explain a bit better please?

Answer (score 2):

In your RowDataBound event of GridView add below line:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```

**Note:** You have to add OnRowDataBound event to GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dg1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="dg1_RowDataBound">
```